# How can we increase or decrease the size of dialog box so that it can also change the size of all the button and menu also in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

```cpp
void CMFCApplication6Dlg::OnFontIncreasefont()
{

    /*LPCTSTR text = _T("Hello World");
    SetDlgItemTextW(IDD_MFCAPPLICATION6_DIALOG,text);*/

    Correct rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    

x = rect.Height();
    int y = rect.Width();
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y << endl;
    SetWindowPos(NULL, 200, 300, x + 150, y + 10, SWP_NOMOVE);
    CFont font;
    font.CreateFont(
        fon + 5,                        // nHeight
        0,                         // nWidth
        0,                         // nEscapement
        0,                         // nOrientation
        FW_NORMAL,                 // nWeight
        FALSE,                     // bItalic
        FALSE,                     // bUnderline
        0,                         // cStrikeOut
        ANSI_CHARSET,              // nCharSet
        OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // nOutPrecision
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,       // nClipPrecision
        DEFAULT_QUALITY,           // nQuality
        DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS,  // nPitchAndFamily
        _T("Arial"));                 // lpszFacename

    fon = fon + 5;
    GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC1)->SetFont(&font);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC2)->SetFont(&font);
    GetDlgItem(IDOK)->SetFont(&font);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT2)->SetFont(&font);
}
```

I want to change the diagonal size in such way that all the button and menu size should change on the same time.

I have tried above code but it will take all the id of menu or button manually , but what i need is that that should be done automatically.

Comment: The system has no provision for automatic dialog layout. The best you could do is look into MFC's [dynamic layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dynamic-layout) implementation. It's very sketchy, and only addresses the most mundane resizing scenarios. You'll have to evaluate whether this is sufficient for your use case (you cannot resize the menu bar).

Comment: the how can i change the position of button with respect of changing in diagonal size , so that it will look arranged.

Comment: If you want to move a window you call the [`MoveWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow) API (or [`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) if you need more control).

Comment: I am suspecting you have a problem of cycle lifetime of your `font` variable, as it gets destroyed when that function finishes. I suggest you to try to make it a member of the class instead of local.

Comment: @sergiol i have done that too , but still the size of button is not increasing .

Comment: I have done manually by changing Sizing Type and Moving Type in properties of every single button and they started working properly but i want to do that automatically by program , so if you have any idea please do let me know  @Vlad Feinstein

Comment: @AmanAnand For resizing in function of what is inside the button, the best thing you can try is `CMFCButton::SizeToContent` and  `CMFCMenuButton::SizeToContent`. But you have to do it one by one. Notice they are not `CButton` class objects, but derived classes which extend the standard `CButton` functionality.

Comment: that's the issue  , I can't it manually, I need to do it automatically

Comment: is there any way that we can connect parents dialog and child dialog in such ways that if we change the font or button size of parents dialog ,it will implement on child dialogs too. @IInspectable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried above code but it will take all the id of menu or button manually , but what i need is that that should be done automatically.

You can automate that with a simple loop:

```
font.DeleteObject();
font.CreateFont(...);
for (CWnd* wnd = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); wnd != NULL; wnd = wnd->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
{
  wnd->SetFont(&font);
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your response, but still it is only increasing the font size of static text, but i also want to change the button(every type of button) , menu size.

Comment: @AmanAnand It works for all controls. Make sure that your font is NOT a local variable (that will be destructed at the end of the function call), instead declare it as a your dialog class member.

Comment: I had tried to declare that as dialog class member but the issues that i am getting are in first go it is working properly but after second time , program is getting break and showing error as you application has breakpoint .

Comment: @AmanAnand You can't re-assign a new font (or any other GDI object), you need to delete the previous object first. I've added that part to my answer.

Comment: yea, but the size of button is not increasing properly, it's looking like text inside the button is getting hide if they are getting increase, because text is only getting increase not the box of button.

Comment: and also the position of button and everything is being fixed but I want them to change there position according to the increment or decrement, so that it should look effective.  Thanks

Comment: @AmanAnand I answered the part about font scaling. The dynamic layout was addressed by IInspectable in his first comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dynamic-layout?view=msvc-170

Comment: is there any way that we can connect parents dialog and child dialog in such ways that if we change the font or button size of parents dialog ,it will implement on child dialogs too. @Vlad Feinstein